# AngularJS UI-Router default views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's the example code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jXEQ9xemL1A5b9KKKcAw?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('npAdmin', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('common', {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.common.html',
        abstract: true,
        // views: {
        //   'footer': {
        //     templateUrl: 'footer.html'
        //   }
        // }
      })
      .state('common.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
          'content': {
            template: '<div><h4>dashboard</h4></div>'
          },
          'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'footer.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('common.crm', { 
        url: '/crm',
        views: {
          'content': {
            template: '<div><h4>CRM</h4></div>'
          },
          'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'footer.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('common.abc', {
        url: '/abc',
        views: {
          'content': {
            template: '<div><h4>ABC</h4></div>'
          },
          'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'newfooter.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('landing', {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.login.html',
        abstract: true,
      })
      .state('landing.login', {
        url: '/login',
        template: '<div><h4>Wow</h4></div>',
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/crm');
  }
]);
```

The default `'templateUrl'` of `'footer'` is *'footer.html'*, but it's *'newfooter.html'* for some state.

Is there a good way to set default footer in this case?

I tried to use `'templateUrl'` and `'views'` at the same time, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jpXsQ9vqeyFs6IfO9BE?p=preview). We can use absolute naming in the parent 'common':

```
  .state('common', {
    
    abstract: true,
     views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.common.html',   
      },
       'footer@common': {
         templateUrl: 'footer.html'
       }
     }
  })
```

And override it only if needed (*'dashboard'* and *'crm'* will use the parent footer, while the **'abc'** is defining an override - special one: newfooter.html)

```
  .state('common.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
      'content': {
        template: '<div><h4>dashboard</h4></div>'
      },
      // provided by parent
      //'footer': {
      //  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
      //}
    }
  })
  .state('common.crm', { 
    url: '/crm',
    views: {
      'content': {
        template: '<div><h4>CRM</h4></div>'
      },
      // provided by parent
      //'footer': {
      //  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
      //}
    }
  })
  .state('common.abc', {
    url: '/abc',
    views: {
      'content': {
        template: '<div><h4>ABC</h4></div>'
      },
      'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'newfooter.html'
      }
    }
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jpXsQ9vqeyFs6IfO9BE?p=preview)

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.
>
> For example, the previous example could also be written as:

```
.state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters@': { },
      'tabledata@': { },
      'graph@': { }
    }
})
```

Comment: I really appreciate it!